# I have a matrix in which each element is a label and a value. How can I represent it so that the label gives the color and the value the intensity?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
    [[[0, 1], [0, 7], [1, 6], [0, 5], [0, 5]]
     [[0, 1], [1, 6], [1, 5], [1, 4], [0, 3]]
     [[1, 1], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
     [[0, 1], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 8]]
     [[0, 1], [0, 5], [1, 4], [0, 3], [0, 3]]]
```

How can I represent it so that the first number gives the color and the second gives the intensity of the color?

Comment: please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. do you want to convert the lists to and image?

Comment: You might want to look up color encodings on the internet. In particular it is not clear how you want to turn a single number (instead of e.g. RGB values) into a color.

Comment: Ok, I want something like a heatmap but the color to be determined by the label.

Comment: You ***could*** use a dictionary to map the first index to an _arbitrary_ color, defined in terms of its `hue` and `saturation`, and use the second index, in terms of a possible min and max of the index, to compute a `value`, where `hue` `saturation` and `value` are inteded as the term in `hsv`, i.e., the Hue Saturation Value color model.   If this is what you want to do I could help for the implementation...

Comment: I want to use it to represent a SOM rectangulary map. The saturation can be standard for all. But I don't know how to use a dictionary for that.

Comment: IIUC, the OP states "so that the first number gives the color"... So I assume, this results in binary colors because if you choose the first element of each sublists, you get only 0 and 1. The desired figure is I think a binary colormap where each pixel/box has a alpha value (intensity) equal to the second element of the sublist. So if you take `arr=np.array(data)`, then the array to eb plotted is `arr[:, :, 0]` and the intensity/alpha values are `arr[:, :, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`hsv_to_rgb`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb.html) can be used to convert from [hue-saturation-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) to rgb values.

`hue` determines the color. `hsv_to_rgb` wants its parameters from 0 to 1, and `hue` is a circular scale, so 0 and 1 map to the same color (red). 0.5 would be the opposite color (cyan).

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV): *the `value`dimension resembling the mixture of those paints with varying amounts of black or white paint*. Just dividing the given values by the largest gets everything in the range 0-1. Other transformations are possible, e.g. `1-value/8`. You might also want to avoid the very dark colors, e.g. by adding some constant, e.g.: `(value + 4) / (numValues + 4)`

`saturation` controls the range between a "full color" (1) and an equivalent gray value (0).

If there aren't too many classes and values, there is if even room for a custom legend.

The code below supposes classes are numbered starting from 0, and values starting from 1.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb

img = [[[0, 1], [0, 7], [1, 6], [0, 5], [0, 5]],
       [[0, 1], [1, 6], [1, 5], [1, 4], [0, 3]],
       [[1, 1], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]],
       [[0, 1], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 8]],
       [[0, 1], [0, 5], [1, 4], [0, 3], [0, 3]]]

numClasses = 2 # numbered 0,1,...
numValues = 8 # numbered 1,2,3,...
img_rgb = [[hsv_to_rgb((hue/numClasses, 1, value/numValues)) 
            for hue, value in row]
           for row in img]
plt.imshow(img_rgb, interpolation='none')

legend_handles = [Patch(facecolor='none' if value==0 else hsv_to_rgb((hue / numClasses, 1, value / numValues)),
                        edgecolor='none',
                        label=f'Class {hue}' if value == 0 else f'V{value}')
                  for hue in range(numClasses) for value in range(0, numValues + 1)]
plt.legend(handles=legend_handles, ncol=numClasses, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=[1, 1])
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.7) # extra space to fit the legend
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: IIUC, the OP states "so that the first number gives the color"... So I assume, this results in binary colors because if you choose the first element of each sublists, you get only 0 and 1. The desired figure is I think a binary colormap where each pixel/box has a alpha value (intensity) equal to the second element of the sublist

Comment: Well, my answer is just a suggestion how the given tuples could be converted to an rgb image. The `v` of `hsv` has a somewhat similar effect as alpha on a black or a white background. OP is free to make many more variations, especially to compare results with the hoped-for result. It is unclear what the exact application and meaning of these numbers are. Nor do we know whether the example shows the full range of desired possibilities.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about. Thank you! So if I have more classes or more values it would be hsv_to_rgb(hue/numClasses, 1, value/numValues).

Comment: Hey! So I added this implementation to my code but I get this "Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)." and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Looking again at your data, I see your values go from `1` to `numValues` and not from `0`till `numValues-1`. So here you should divide by `numValues` to make sure the outcome will be between 0 and 1. Or do `(value - 1) / (numValues - 1)`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I got it! I was trying to normalize the values(some or 20 and others ore 3000 and the small ones turn up black) and I was messsing it up there but your answear made me realize what was the problem.